# Ruby Core: Access the Case/When item without assigning to variable

Tags: ruby

Is there any local variable you can use in a `case`/`when` situation.

For example:

```
case [1,2,3].each
when ->(n){n.to_a.empty?}
  puts "empty"
else
  # Get the current Enumerator object here
  <this> do |i|
    puts "The number is #{i}"
  end
end
```

When you call `self` within the else block it returns the `main` object.  The only thing that shows up with `local_variables` is `[:_]`.  I see that I can hand in the current item with `when` in the **proc** `->(){}`.  But I've been unable to access it with `then`, `else`, or even inside the `when` block.

I'm not looking to assign it with `case this=[1,2,3].each`.  I'm specifically asking for a further insight of `case`/`when` in regards of using the object in play.

To further illustrate the question as **people are misunderstanding the Enumerator**.

### Take this example:

```
case "a"
when ->(n){n.next!.equal?("c")}
  puts "c"
when ->(n){n.next!.equal?("b")}
  puts "b"
when ->(n){n.next!.equal?("a")}
  puts "a"
else
  puts "The state failed to match up."
  # GET ACTUAL VALUE HERE?
end
# => The state failed to match up.
```

**This is a proof that the object is being changed within `case`.**  It works.  Yet I have no known way to access what the current value is.  **That is the question I seek an answer to.**

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? `case` will be executed only once, not for every element in the array.

Comment: `case` is a control flow operator, why do you expect it to define smth inside it? You did not expect there is magic `$_` inside `if`, right?

Comment: I've updated the question as you seem to have missed the point.  State can change on the object even when it's not a **"declared"** local variable.  So I want to know what **"it"** is as the changes occur.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need a loop, not a switch.

Comment: I'm well aware of how loops work.  I'm not looking to build this loop.  I'm asking for the way to accomplish this with the case/when block.  I would expect something like `$1` or `$_` to hold a current object.